# Adding multiple SelectElement into IList for iteration

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am trying to iterate into multiple drop-down boxes and select value in each one of them, now the drop-down boxes are variable, is there a way to do that, I tried this:

```
   IList<SelectElement> allDropDowns = mydrive.FindElements(By.CssSelector
(".custom-select.fileType.form-control"));
```

Answer (score 0):

After working on it, I got the solution (or atleast it works !)

```
  IList<IWebElement> allDropDowns = mydrive.FindElements
(By.CssSelector(".custom-select.fileType.form-control"));
```

Then assign each list item to `SelectEelement`

```
  SelectElement selectFileType = new SelectElement(allDropDowns[index]);
```